# How to move data between 2 tables / with different columns in different databases with multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert, sql-insert

INSERT INTO a2.cat (id, img) SELECT category_id, category_id FROM topshop.category;

all I need to insert plus values in the column img from the category_-id

```
INSERT INTO a2.cat (id, 'c'+img+'.jpg') SELECT category_id, category_id FROM topshop.category;
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Sample data and desired results perhaps would be helpful.

Comment: I want to convert old site database to opencart database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here it is:

```
INSERT INTO a2.cat 
  (id, img) 
SELECT 
  category_id, CONCAT('c',category_id,'.jpg')
FROM topshop.category;
```

Comment: this working fine, but what if there is some values want to insert another extension